# MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. when using Hebrew chars

Tags: java, xml, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse XML file which contains Hebrew chars.
I know that the file is correct because if I output the file (from a different software) without the hebrew chars, it parses just fine.

I tried many things, but I always get this error

```
MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

My latest attempt was to open it using `FileInputStream` and specify the encoding

```
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
document = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFileName)), "Cp1252");
```

(`Cp1252` is an encoding that worked for me in a different app)
But I got the same result.

Tried using `ByteArray` as well, nothing worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the file encoded? What api are you using to parse it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what encoding the file has. It's missing the encoding part in the first line.. I'm using java's built in DocumentBuilder.parse

Comment: the second argument to parse is a system id, not a character encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you know the correct encoding of the file and it's not "utf-8", then you can either add it to the xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="[correct encoding here]" ?>
```

or parse it as a Reader:

```
db.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(xmlFileName)), "[correct encoding here]"));
```

Comment: I ended up doing that exactly. Actually I did both of them, and it works.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple, get the content in UTF-8 format, and override the SAX input source.

```
File file = new File("c:\\file-utf.xml");
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
// is.setEncoding("UTF-8"); -> This line causes error! Content is not allowed in prolog

saxParser.parse(is, handler);
```

You can read the full example here – http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/